# Enumerating Through Child Nodes as different Type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to enumerate through all of the sprite nodes which I have subclassed as VillainSquirrel (as you can see below), and I am trying to access properties specific to the VillainSquirrel Class... however, I am running into difficulties.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Tuple types '(SKNode, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>)' and '()' have a different number of elements (2 vs. 0)
```

Here is what I do to try to enumerate through the  nodes as VillainSquirrel:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("villainType1") {
        node as! VillainSquirrel, stop in
        if (node.position.y > self.size.height){
            node.brownMarker.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x, self.size.height - 10)
            node.brownMarker.zPosition = 1
            self.addChild(node.brownMarker)
        }
    }
```

Here's my VillainSquirrel Class (or at least the beginning of it):

```
class VillainSquirrel: SKSpriteNode {
  var brownMarker = SKSpriteNode()
  var brownMarkerVisible: Bool

  override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: SKColor, size: CGSize) {

    self.brownMarker.zPosition = 1
    self.brownMarker.xScale = 0.25
    self.brownMarker.yScale = 0.25
    self.brownMarker = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"brownMarkerTrans.png")
...
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
   self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("villainType1") {
        node, stop in

        let realnode = node as! VillainSquirrel
        if (node.position.y > self.size.height){
            realnode.brownMarker.position = CGPointMake(realnode.position.x, self.size.height - 10)
            realnode.brownMarker.zPosition = 1
            if (!realnode.brownMarkerVisible){
                self.addChild(realnode.brownMarker)
                realnode.brownMarkerVisible = true
            }
        }
        else if (realnode.brownMarkerVisible){
            realnode.brownMarkerVisible = false
            realnode.brownMarker.removeFromParent()

        }
    }
```

I just had to typeCast the node as my subclassed spriteNode in the block, I couldn't do it with node, stop in